# ActivitySource.StartActivity returns null as if there is no listeners even though console listener is defined

Tags: c#, profiling, jaeger, open-telemetry

The code uses Console Trace Provider. However, In the function  static void MakeActivity(string name),
The line ActivitySource.startActivity returns a null. How can i fix it?

The examples on google have the "using" keyword which i cannot apply with .net 4.7 with which my project id bound against.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Starts up the OpenTelemetry and JeagerTracing connection
    /// </summary>
  using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static ResourceBuilder BackendServiceResource { get; set; }

            private static readonly ActivitySource ActivitySource = new ActivitySource("Sample.DistributedTracing");

            private static readonly string serveradress = "127.0.0.1";
            private static readonly int serverPort = 6831;

            public static TracerProvider Provider { get; set; }

            public static Tracer OpenTelemetryTracer { get; set; }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            var serviceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService";
            var serviceVersion = "1.0.0";
            Provider = GetConsoleTraceProvider(serviceName, serviceVersion);
                OpenTelemetryTracer = Provider.GetTracer(ActivitySource.Name);

                MakeActivity("Test 1");
                MakeActivity("Test 2");
                MakeActivity("Test 3");
                MakeActivity("Test 4");
                MakeActivity("Test 5");

            }

            static void MakeActivity(string name)
            {
                Activity activity = ActivitySource.StartActivity(name); // this returns null even though i have a trace provider setup using GetConsoleTraceProvider
                activity.AddTag("machine.name", Environment.MachineName); 
                activity.AddTag("user.name", Environment.UserName);

                Task.Delay(5000);

                activity.Stop();
            }

        public static TracerProvider GetConsoleTraceProvider(string serviceName,string serviceVersion)
        {
            // Configure important OpenTelemetry settings and the console exporter
             var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .AddSource(serviceName)
                .SetResourceBuilder(
                    ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                        .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: serviceVersion))
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .Build();
            return tracerProvider;
        }
        


        }
    }
```

vs this code sample works as i am using a c# 10 feature.

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;

// Define some important constants and the activity source
var serviceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyService";
var serviceVersion = "1.0.0";

// Configure important OpenTelemetry settings and the console exporter
using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
    .AddSource(serviceName)
    .SetResourceBuilder(
        ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
            .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: serviceVersion))
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .Build();




var MyActivitySource = new ActivitySource(serviceName);

using var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello");
activity?.SetTag("foo", 1);
activity?.SetTag("bar", "Hello, World!");
activity?.SetTag("baz", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: _The examples on google have the "using" keyword which i cannot apply with .net 4.7 with which my project id bound against._ can you provide more detail, and examples?

Comment: added code sample using c# 10 feature(Using). How can i get my original code fixed as my project is bound to .net 4.7

Comment: Just use braces - see the first example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: The ActivitySource.startActivity is returning null because there's no listener tied to it.  It seems to me there's some auto-magically thing going on when the ActivitySource(servicename) is created that they are doing to attach a listener to the tracer provider.  Looking through the source code and examples hasn't really helped me figure it out either, all I can figure out is the tracer provider creates it's own ActivitySource with the same name.  This has been vexing me for a few days now.

Comment: AddSource() is needed. Thanks you saved me hours!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it needs AddSource() in tracing to work